# Combining valueRenderOptions in spreadsheets.values.get

Tags: google-sheets-api

When using [spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get), there does not seem to be a way to combine [valueRenderOptions](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption).
The reason for doing this would be to use both **FORMULA** and **UNFORMATTED_VALUE** at the same time.
**FORMULA** does not preserve escaped strings. I would like to have both options specified so that my strings come back to me escaped and my formulas come back unresolved.

Comment: Did you get it work?

Comment: Not yet. I coded around it, but thanks for the reminder that I should play with it some more.